# How to fix this simple Makefile error?

Tags: c++, shell, makefile

I'm trying to create a very simple makefile that will build my C++ code as well as create a .txt file

I want the executable and .txt file to be placed in a directory called "build".  In order to do this, I need to make sure the build directory doesn't already exist.  I'm getting a syntax error, and I can't seem to fix it.  This is probably a very obvious mistake, as I'm new to creating makefiles.

Can anyone help?

The error:

`/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [mlib] Error 2`

The Makefile:

```
all:
    if [ ! -d build ]; then
        mkdir build
    fi
    g++ src/*.cpp -o build/mlb
    touch build/mlib_history.txt
```

Comment: This makefile doesn't take advantage of **any** of the things that make does for you and could just as usefully be a shell script.

Comment: Also see the [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell) special target, but as @EtanReisner says your recipe is reinventing the wheel for things that makefile can already handle for you.

Answer (score 1):

I actually fixed it by simply changing the makefile to:

all:

```
if [ ! -d build ]; then mkdir build; fi
#"mkdir build" moved onto the above line
#somehow this fixed it...?
g++ src/*.cpp -o build/mlb
touch build/mlib_history.txt
```

Comment: Each line in a makefile recipe is run in its own shell. To get a shell command to span multiple lines you need to tell make to continue the line (with a backslash on the end of the line).

Comment: Seems easier to just do `mkdir -p build`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly better solution…

```
.PHONY: all

BUILD_DIR := build

all:
    [ ! -d $(BUILD_DIR) ] && mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)
    g++ src/*.cpp -o $(BUILD_DIR)/mlb
    touch $(BUILD_DIR)/mlib_history.txt
```